# Magento - Product Listing Sort By not working

Tags: products, product-list, category-products, product-sorting

For reference, I am working with Magento 2.4

I have tried the solutions from other posts on this forum and online and I cannot seem to get my magento app products sorted in the order I want. I have set the "Default Product Listing Sort By" setting in **Catalog > Categories > Display Settings** to be "Product Name" and also set the "Product Listing Sort By" setting in **Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog** to be "Product Name" as well.

Even when trying this, the products do not sort in order of product name. I have also tried to sort by "Position" and "Price", and still the products do not change their sort order.

I have found that in my case the ordering of products follows the order that they are listed in **Catalog > Categories > Products in Category**, which in my case is ordered by their ID.

Has anyone else had any issues with these settings not working properly? I am new to magento and am unsure of how I can fix these issues.

As a side note: I am more than just an administrator for this project. I am very capable of tweaking the code itself if that is where the solution lies.

Comment: Did u try doing the deployment again after changing the configurations on the admin side?

Comment: @BharathKumarJ yes